# IMAP protocol in Java

Tags: java, imap

Where can I get an opensource library written in Java, especially for the IMAP protocol?

Something like imaplib in Python.

Answer (score 8):

[JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) supports it. Go through [Fundamentals of the JavaMail API](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/pt/fundamentals%20of%20the%20javamail%20api.pdf) and the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html) to get started with it.

Comment: The links are currently broken, I guess the because of Oracle-Sun acquisition. You might want to fix them.

Comment: @palacsint: fixed. The original Sun.com course is by the way available here http://192.9.162.55/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/ which I couldn't paste in due to an IP address instead of a domain.